# Trouble installing a package - "Unable to locate package"

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The specific problem is that I am trying to install a package called py_trees_ros [image: image description] and I get the error unable to install package [image: image description].

The general problem is, how do I troubleshoot these kinds of errors. (I know that I could clone the GitHub repo into my src but I am trying to understand properly what's going on.) Is there a way to get the "master list" of installable packages on my particular computer so I can grep it? Is that list outdated? Does that package actually not exist despite what I see in the wiki?

Any help on the specific case and as well on the general question would be truly appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382524/trouble-installing-a-package---%22unable-to-locate-package%22/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2021-07-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-07-16**:\

> I know that I could clone the GitHub repo into my src but I am trying to understand properly what's going on

please. Don't do this unless you absolutely must.

See #q320046.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-07-16**:
Please tell us how you've installed ROS.

If you didn't use `apt` to install your base ROS packages, you cannot use `apt` to install additional packages.

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2021-07-16**:
Agreed. See below. One thing that I still need to remember or figure out. `apt list *py-trees*` shows me the packages that are available for installing with `apt install xxx`. But what if the package exists (I am sure) but it doesn't show up? What is the command that allows apt list to even see the packages? What is the mechanism there?

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2021-07-19**:
If the package is available in an apt repository, but you don't see it with `apt list`, it probably means the repository that contains the package is not (properly) configured on your system.  For the standard ROS repositories that's handled in [steps 1.1 - 1.3 in the installation wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Ubuntu#Installation.2FUbuntu.2FSources-5.Configure_your_Ubuntu_repositories).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure what's happening with this specific package, but `apt list *py-trees-ros` will list all available packages in the repositories ending with "py-trees-ros".  My output is:

```
Listing... Done
ros-dashing-py-trees-ros/bionic 1.2.1-2bionic.20210521.230415 amd64
ros-eloquent-py-trees-ros/bionic 2.0.11-1bionic.20201207.172830 amd64
ros-melodic-py-trees-ros/bionic 0.5.21-1bionic.20210505.044943 amd64
```

I'm on Ubuntu Bionic right now, so it's not surprising that a Noetic package isn't listed.  It's worth checking that your ROS repositories are set up correctly ([wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Ubuntu#Installation.2FUbuntu.2FSources-5.Configure_your_Ubuntu_repositories)).  As mentioned in [issue 162 on GitHub](https://github.com/splintered-reality/py_trees_ros/issues/162), all indications are that the Noetic packages should be available in the ROS repositories.

---

Originally posted by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) with karma: 1421 on 2021-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2021-07-16**:
I knew this command had to exist but I wasn't sure what it was. It turned out that I was on a different computer where I had melodic and not noetic. Dumb. But as I said in the original question, I was trying to learn the right way to diagnose the problem. Thanks